# Subject line not coming in the smtp mail sent from python

Tags: python, email, smtp

My code is running and sending the mail. 
But **To** and **Subject** are not coming in the mail. Here is a snippet of the code i used. What could be the issue?

Code :

```
   username = "N@EXAMPLE.com"
   password = "fnEOFINO”


   print("Logged in")

   sender = 'n@example.com'
   receivers = 'T@example.com'
   message = """From: Neeraja Rajiv  <NRajiv@EXAMPLE.com>
   To: T@EXAMPLE.COM 
   Subject: SMTP e-mail test

   Overall
   %d
                                               """%(variable)
   print("Connecting to server")

   server = smtplib.SMTP('SMTP-********.com', 25)
   print("Connected to server")
   server.set_debuglevel (1)
   server.sendmail(sender,receivers,message)         
   print ("Successfully sent email")
```

In the Email, subject is missing.

Any approaches/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: how are you attaching the subject?

Comment: Doesn't it get attached as a string?Also I tried removing the quotes.If I put the to and subject in the same line as from, it appears in the from line, all three. If i insert a space between from and to the "To" and "Subject" becomes a part of the mail

Comment: show the rest of your code

Comment: working fine, why did you not post that in the first place?

Comment: Hi Padraic. I just wanted to convey that i am passing a variable.This code works fine as a standalone code. But am trying to make a sendmail function. This does not work becausewhile defining inside the function somehow the indentation creates a problem. It doesn't display To and Subject

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No error . the mail gets sent but no Subject and no from

Comment: without seeing your function it is impossible to tell the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in how you have created your message, the corrected version  works using it with the example code below:

```
msg = """From: 'From Neeraja Rajiv  <NRajiv@EXAMPLE.com>'
To: 'To Toffet Joseph - Consultant <TJoseph@EXAMPLE.com>'
Subject: 'SMTP e-mail test'
Overall'{}'""".format(variable)

username = "foo"
password = "bar"

print("Logged in")

import smtplib
sender = "foo@gmail.com"
receivers = "bar@gmail.com"
msg = """From: 'From Neeraja Rajiv  <NRajiv@EXAMPLE.com>'
To: 'To Toffet Joseph - Consultant <TJoseph@EXAMPLE.com>'
Subject: 'SMTP e-mail test'"""

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(sender, receivers , msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Tried this. The subject still doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Padraic Cunningham example looks correct. Here is another example. Maybe this might help...

Sample Email To SMTP Server Python Script:

import smtplib

try:

```
host = '?.?.?.?'                                              #The Address To Your SMTP Server...
port = 25

to = 'reciever@someplace.com'                                 #Reciever Of Email...
from_addr = 'sender@someplace.com'                            #Sender Of Email...

subject = '<YOUR SUBJECT HERE>'                               #Subject Of Email...

text_line_1 = 'Body Line 1...\r\n'                            #Body Of Email...
text_line_2 = '\r\n'
text_line_3 = 'Body Line 3...\r\n'
text_line_4 = '\r\n'
text_line_5 = 'Body Line 5...\r\n'

total_message = text_line_1 + text_line_2 + text_line_3 + text_line_4 + text_line_5 

msg = "From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s" % (from_addr, [to], subject, total_message)

server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
server.sendmail(from_addr, to, msg)

print('Successfully Sent Email...')
```

except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: ' + str(e))

Good Luck...