# Missing subject line on email sent using smptlib

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm trying to send out an email using python's smptlib, which seems to be working fine except the subject key does not get attached. (image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkpLh.png)

I've looked at other solutions but none of them work for me. They are solving mostly for text based additions in the form of headers but my code involves sending a dataframe as a table which gets messed up when I try these solutions.

Posts I've looked at:

[Python: "subject" not shown when sending email using smtplib module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232088/python-subject-not-shown-when-sending-email-using-smtplib-module)

[Subject line not coming in the smtp mail sent from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056789/subject-line-not-coming-in-the-smtp-mail-sent-from-python)

[Python smtplib sendmail() not working with subject / body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754003/python-smtplib-sendmail-not-working-with-subject-body)

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from tabulate import tabulate

sender = 'email@email.com'
recipients = 'email@email.com'
subject = "Test Email 1234"


# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
msg['Subject'] = subject

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).

text = """

text

{table}


text

"""

html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center;}}
 th, td {{ padding: 8px; }}


</style>
</head>

<body><p>text </p>
<br><br><br>
{table}
<br><br><br>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>abc</p>
</body></html>
"""


col_list = list(df.columns.values)
data = df
# above line took every col inside csv as list
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers=col_list, tablefmt="html"))




msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])



# Send the message via local SMTP server.
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("email@gmail.com", "pw")
server.sendmail(sender,recipients, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings

```
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
msg['Subject'] = subject
```

will be overwritten, as soon as you do

```
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
```

later on.

Just switch their order and remove the first `msg = MIMEMultipart()`.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for this solution! Didn't realize I was doing this :)